# Adding variable to document.title

Tags: javascript, variables, title

Hopefully a quick and easy one. I'm trying to organize a page title swap when the page loses focus like the Invision Blog, I have the code below which works perfectly for the actual functionality.

The only issue is bringing in the count variable which isn't outputting and provides no errors either.

```
var title = document.title,
    count = $(".itemCount").text();
newTitle = "You have " + count + " items still in your basket " + title;
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
    document.title = ((document.hidden) ? newTitle : title);
});
```

and the HTML of the class is:

```
<span class="itemCount cornersSmall">20</span>
```

I am using jQuery 1.11.0

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The newTitle output itself appears fine as have tried it with repeating the title variable again and works fine so can only assume there is an issue with picking up the itemCount text.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: Can you show your html, at least the elements with .itemCount class?

Comment: If setting the title otherwise works then the problem is obviously not with `document.title` but getting the variable value in the first place.

Comment: @byronpinn Don't put it here. [edit] your question instead.

Comment: I hope you've jQuery included on your page!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, seems to work fine for me.. What version jQuery are you using? What browser?

Comment: Apologies for the 'noobness' guys. First official question.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that either this code is running before the DOM is set (wrap it inside a document.ready event) or the item count is set dynamically and is in fact empty when you read the value.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the fix. Thanks to all the comments which helped steer the thought process direction. This is the code that worked.

```
(function ($) {
var itemCount = parseInt($('#basketPreviewPanel .itemCount').text())
if (itemCount > 0) {
    var title = document.title;
    newTitle = "You have items still in your basket | " + title;
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
        document.title = ((document.hidden) ? newTitle : title);
    });
}
}(window.jQuery));
```

As you can see the output changed a little due to issues with the count not updating due to ajax issues so stuck with a more generic message and using JS to pick up the number and use that as an IF statement.